# VBA Run-time error on sending mail (Office 2013)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-office

Below a VBA code written for Office 2007 but running on Office 2013 I get a Run-time error

```
Run-time error '2147417851 (800010105)'
Method 'SendOnBehalfOfName' of object '_MailItem' failed
```

Below the code:

```
Dim outobj As Object

Set outobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mail = outobj.CreateItem(0)

With Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Support")
    mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = .Range(.Range("B:B").Find("Sender").Address).Offset(0, 1)
    mail.To = .Range(.Range("B:B").Find("To1").Address).Offset(0, 1)
    mail.Cc = .Range(.Range("B:B").Find("To2").Address).Offset(0, 1)
    mail.Subject = .Range(.Range("B:B").Find("Obj").Address).Offset(0, 1)
    attach = .Range(.Range("B:B").Find("Attach").Address).Offset(0, 1)
    Dim strBody As String
    strBody = "Attached the Daily Report and below relevant statistics." & vbCrLf _
    & " " & vbCrLf _
    & .Range(.Range("B:B").Find("text1").Address).Offset(0, 1) 

    mail.Body = strBody

End With
```

Comment: Works fine on my machine - is this the whole code?

Comment: What is the actual value/string you are trying to assign to the `SentOnBehalfOfName` property?

Answer (score 0):

The [SentOnBehalfOfName](http://odc.officeapps.live.com/odc/help/clientdeveloper?lcid=1033&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&ver=15&helpnamespace=OUTLOOK&helpid=vbaol11.chm1360) property makes sense only in case of Exchange profiles. If so, do you have the permission to send on behalf of another user?

If you use POP3/SMTP accounts you need to use the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311(v=office.15).aspx) property instead.